# Sort ArrayList of Array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

What is the best way to sort an `ArrayList<String[]>` in Java?

Where `String[]` is...

```
String[] strAarray = new String[] { "abc", "abc", "abc", "abc", "abc", "abc", "abc" };
```

Now I want to sort the whole ArrayList by the 2nd value of `String[]` (at index 1). I need to loop through each and every `String[]` and then its child at index 1.

Any ideas?

Edit:

---

I have more descriptions. I am actually getting schools from some XML file and every node in XML has 7 attributes. Now I am creating an ArrayList of `String[]` which is holding those school nodes from XML and `String[] strArray` itself is holding attributes of particular node.

Now, the way I want to sort it is, it should sort according to State of school which is the 2nd attribute in XML and index 1 in `String[]` inside ArrayList.

I need to loop through each and every School first (node in XML, `String[]` in Java) and then I will have to filter State (State attribute in XML, `String[1]` in Java).

Comment: I don't see any ArrayList anywhere, and everything in your string array is identical...

Comment: Please try explain it a bit futher, post some input parameters and excepted results.

Comment: You would be well served by using objects instead of lists, arrays, and strings.  Java's an object-oriented language.  You're having trouble because you're thinking at too low a level  XML is not a good abstraction.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Start with [Collections.sort, the one that takes a custom Comparator](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator)).  You'll need to write a custom [Comparator](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) for this also.

For instance, assuming you want to rely on the natural ordering of Strings as defined in their compareTo method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ArrayList<String[]> listOfStringArrays = new ArrayList<String[]>();
        listOfStringArrays.add(new String[] {"x","y","z"});
        listOfStringArrays.add(new String[] {"a","b","c"});
        listOfStringArrays.add(new String[] {"m","n","o"});
        Collections.sort(listOfStringArrays,new Comparator<String[]>() {
            public int compare(String[] strings, String[] otherStrings) {
                return strings[1].compareTo(otherStrings[1]);
            }
        });
        for (String[] sa : listOfStringArrays) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sa));
        }
        /* prints out 
          [a, b, c]
          [m, n, o]
          [x, y, z]
        */ 

    }
```

Comment: Note that this is actually sorting by index 1. If you change the "y" to "a" then it'll print out as is ordered.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this comment. The question asks for sorting based on index 1.  The order of the input does't matter.

Answer (score 4):

You create a `Comparator<String[]>` like so:

```
new Comparator<String[]>() {
  public int compare(String[] first, String[] second) {
    return first[1].compareTo(second[1]);
  }
}
```

then pass it to `Collections.sort()`.

You might want to do some checking if the second element is actually present in the array. You could also do a custom comparison if the standard String comparison isn't enough.

Comment: I am thinking how it would sort the whole ArrayList by State in ascending order?

Comment: It would be in ascending order the way both Jorn and I presented it.  if you wanted it in another order, then you could either negate the value returned from String.compareTo(String) or just call Collections.reverse(yourList) after you've sorted the first time.

Answer (score 3):

You write a `Comparator` that compares two `String[]` by the correct child, and then you pass it to `Collections.sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c)`.

Answer (score 3):

This is extremely easy to do with Java 8. Just write:

```
list.sort(Comparator.comparing(a -> a[1]));
```

For example, the following code:

```
List<String[]> list = Arrays.asList(
    new String[] { "abc", "abc", "abc", "abc", "abc", "abc", "abc" },
    new String[] { "xyz", "xyz", "xyz", "xyz", "xyz", "xyz", "xyz" },
    new String[] { "fgh", "fgh", "fgh", "fgh", "fgh", "fgh", "fgh" });

list.sort(Comparator.comparing(a -> a[1]));
list.stream().map(Arrays::toString).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Will yield the wanted result:

```
[abc, abc, abc, abc, abc, abc, abc]
[fgh, fgh, fgh, fgh, fgh, fgh, fgh]
[xyz, xyz, xyz, xyz, xyz, xyz, xyz]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use TreeSet or TreeMap http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html

Answer (score 0):

Based on your edit:  Your String[] should be a School object to contain your attributes.  Make your School object implement Comparable and that will allow easy sorting with Collections.sort().

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have a list of arrays `[["x", "y","z"], ["a", "b", "c"], ["m", "n", "o"]]`

We can use list.sort() instead of Collections.sort().

To sort, we can adopt a cleaner way using lambdas and method references.

Using lambda:

```java
listOfStrings.sort((a, b)->a[1].compareTo(b[1]));
```

Using method reference:

```java
listOfStrings.sort(Comparator.comparing(a->a[1]));
```

Outputs:

```java
[a, b, c]
[m, n, o]
[x, y, z]
```