# Sort list of string[] in java

Tags: java

I have `List<String[]>`. I would like to have it sorted by name in `String[3]` in alphabetic order. How should my comparator look like for such case ?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: "sorted by name in String[3]" - what exactly do you want ?

Comment: How would you do it for `List<String>`?

Comment: [`Collections.sort(List, Comparator)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator)). Note that I don't post an answer since **it's your duty try something** and then asking about the problems you have, not asking people to do things for you.

Comment: [Close enough](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4699807/sort-arraylist-of-array-in-java)? Took me about 10 seconds to find.

Comment: @Dukeling want to also give a cup of coffee and a cookie to OP while reading the answer he/she should have looked for?

Comment: Well I found it an interesting question. Not sure why so many downvotes.

Comment: @djaqeel Because: 1) [Googling it](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+sort+list+of+arrays) instantly gives you a solution. 2) OP hasn't appeared to try anything (which probably isn't that good a reason in this case).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<String[]>() {
        public int compare(String[] o1, String[] o2) {
            return o1[3].compareTo(o2[3]);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Oh, **that** is what the op was wanting... +1 from me. Still think the question was a dup though.

Comment: +1, what an elegant way of doing it.